# How is compilation unit defined in c++?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compilationunit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What is a “translation unit” in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)

It is often said that the static variables declared in C/C++ are not visible across compilation units ? Does this mean that each .c or .cpp file is a separate compilation unit ? What about a .h file  and the static variables declared in the .h file ? Is .h file also considered as a separate compilation unit ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c

Comment: Technically a duplicate, but that presumes that you know that a "compilation unit" is the same as a "translation unit".

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Header files have no separate life, only their content is `#included` into .c or .cpp files. But since `#include` is handled by the preprocessor, the compiler has no knowledge about distinct header files; it only sees the resulting code listing as input. This is what is called a *compilation unit*: a source file with all its `#include` directives replaced by the content of the relevant header files and all other preprocessor statements processed (like `#define`, `#ifdef` etc.).

Comment: This question could be interpreted as duplicated, but the answer is much more instructive than the answer of the original question

Comment: ... minus any lines excluded by conditional preprocessor directives.

Answer (score 12):

C and C++ compilation is (usually) divided in three independent steps:

- Preprocessing, involving macro and #include expansions.
- Compiling, converting source code to binary code and generating intermediante object files.
- Linking, joining the object files in a single ELF or EXE file.

Wherever there is an `#include` or a macro, the preprocessor expands that expression with the actual value. In the case of an `#include` that entire line is replaced with the .h file contents.

The actual compiler is (usually) not aware of any header file, it sees a compilation unit as a big .c or .cpp file.

The "usually" part comes from the fact that some compilers optimizes header inclusion by storing a precompiled header in some sort of cache, but the effect is the same.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler only processes source files, usually with the extension .c or .cpp. The compiler doesn't really care about the files that are included: as far as the compiler is usually implemented, each .c/.cpp file is processed anew, whatever .h files are read (courtesy of the preprocessor).

This is why we talk about 'compilation units': something that is compiled in one go, the results of which may subsequently be linked together into executables.