# Undefined reference constructor while compiling C++ code

Tags: c++, g++, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I receive the following error when I try to compile three c++ files with `g++ main.cpp`. If I combine them in one file, it works.

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `Time::Time()'
```

Time.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Time.h"
using namespace std;

Time::Time()
{
    a=5;
}
```

Time.h

```
#ifndef TIME_H
#define TIME_H

class Time {

public:
Time();
private:
int a;
};
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Time.h" 
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    Time t;
}
```

Comment: You will need to tell the compiler to compile Time.cpp as well.  For example: `g++ main.cpp Time.cpp -o main`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile **all** the CPP files because each one is a separate [compilation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Compilation_Unit)

```
g++ main.cpp Time.cpp -o main
```

For more information about that read

- [How is compilation unit defined in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4992247/995714)
- [What is a "translation unit" in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1106149/995714)

Comment: is there a shortcut? what about if I have more than 100 files?

Comment: if you have that many files then you must create a [makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile), otherwise you'll end up compiling a file again and again. In MSVC or some other IDEs just create a new solution/project and the IDE will handle the compilation for you

Comment: You could use shell expansion, e.g. `g++ *.cpp -o main`